# Does the White Walker induction ceremony exist in the books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, book-adaptation

On what basis or with what reference was the White Walker induction ceremony included in the [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) episode "Oathkeeper" (S04E04) and where is it referred to in the books?

Comment: Are you talking about conversion of child into white walker?

Comment: Yes , the conversion of craster's last born into a white walker

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding the content in the literature on which it is based. I feel it would be a better fit on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: I don't see how it is off topic. Even if it's not in the literature, it's asking a question based on something that happened on the show.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Better fit elsewhere? Maybe, but that's utterly irrelevant, given that it's on-topic here, too.

Comment: This is more of a clarification for the book reader than the TV Series follower. To me it seems like the OP has read the book, and is now trying to find out how the TV Series fits into it. Simply put, its not a question about GoT Series, rather the Song of Ice and Fire novels.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher To me it sounds like a question asking about what, if anything, a certain part of a TV show is based on in the source material. It seems a question about both.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I do agree, its a question about both. To my eyes it just seemed a little laden towards the books. That's the reason I said it'd be a better fit on Sci-Fi or maybe a Literature site. However, I am going to retract my close vote looking at the answer. The question has merit here too.

Comment: Rule of thumb:  Don't worry about whether it's on-topic (or more on-topic) elsewhere. The only test should be whether it's of legitimate interest to *this* community, and this one seems to easily pass that test from my view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This **is not mentioned** in the books. No one had ever seen it before.

This can mean two things:

1. This will be in one of the next books; hence the TV Show is starting to spoil the book series.
2. This won't happen in the books, and it was just on the show.

Either way, we cannot know what that scene meant/was based on/referenced/whatever until the next season and/or book come out

Comment: Although not stated *explicitly* there are *implicit* references re Craster and his sons.